# Conditional image rules inside GridView TemplateField

Tags: asp.net, gridview, templatefield, iif

I need to display a red/orange/green icon inside a GridView column based on the values in the GridView. I've managed to show the red/green, but I'm having trouble showing the orange icon. The yellow icon needs to appear when the variance between two values is between +/- 5%.

My working code with red/green is as follows:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
 <ItemTemplate>
  <asp:Image ID="Image3" runat="server" Height="20px" ImageUrl='<%# 
  IIF((CType(Container,GridViewRow).RowIndex =2),
    IIF((Eval("A") > Eval("B")),
    "~/Images/Icons/iGreen.png", "~/Images/Icons/iRed.png"),
     IIF((Eval("A") > Eval("B")),
     "~/Images/Icons/iRed.png", "~/Images/Icons/iGreen.png")) %>' Width="20px" />
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

My non-working code is as follows:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
 <ItemTemplate>
  <asp:Image ID="Image3" runat="server" Height="20px" ImageUrl='<%# 
  IIF((CType(Container,GridViewRow).RowIndex =2),
   IIF( abs((Eval("A") / Eval("B"))-1) < 0.05 ,
   "~/Images/Icons/iOrange.png",
    IIF((Eval("A") > Eval("B")),
    "~/Images/Icons/iGreen.png", "~/Images/Icons/iRed.png"),
     IIF((Eval("A") > Eval("B")),
     "~/Images/Icons/iRed.png", "~/Images/Icons/iGreen.png"))) %>' Width="20px" />
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

With the code above I'm getting the following error:

```
'abs' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
```

I've tried aslo instead of 'abs' (absolute value) to use (^2) squared but it doesn't work either.

Any ideas on how I can get this working?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you should try Math.Abs

Comment: Thanks Hans. With Math.Abs i get another error: Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'IIf' accepts this number of arguments.

Comment: I managed to make it work with Math.Abs. Thanks Hans

Answer (score 0):

You could try this, looks like 2 times IIF((Eval("A") > Eval("B")), I removed one

```
'<%# IIF((CType(Container,GridViewRow).RowIndex =2), IIF( Math.Abs((Eval("A") / Eval("B"))-1) < 0.05 ,"~/Images/Icons/iOrange.png",IIF(Eval("A") > Eval("B"), "~/Images/Icons/iGreen.png", "~/Images/Icons/iRed.png")),"3") %>'
```

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to make it work. Thanks Hans for your help. See code below if it helps someone:

Note that I've added A +0.00001 to prevent division by zero. Nesting the code with another condition was still giving me division error (maybe I was doing something wrong)

Also, in row index 2 I need to invert the conditions, where A being smaller is better (green)

```
IIF( Math.Abs((Eval("A") / (Eval("B")+0.00001))-1) < 0.05, 
  "~/Images/Icons/iOrange.png",
  IIF((CType(Container,GridViewRow).RowIndex =2),
    IIF((Eval("A") > Eval("B")),
    "~/Images/Icons/iGreen.png", "~/Images/Icons/iRed.png"
    ),
    IIF((Eval("A") < Eval("B")),
     "~/Images/Icons/iRed.png", "~/Images/Icons/iGreen.png"
    )
  )
 )
```